# Tic, Tac, Toe - End Game error

Tags: python

Thank you for the comments.

I have now solved the original problem and the game ends correctly if one player wins and chooses not to continue.

However, I have now tried to add in whether or not the game is a draw and this does not seem to work.

I have defined a function that checks to see if there are any valid moves left and if there are not it should return the corresponding value to stop the game and print to screen that there is a draw.

It recognises that no one has won but does not trigger the draw response.

```
def start():
    choices = [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "]
    initialboard=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
    board(initialboard)
    getchoice(choices)

def board(choices):
    print("+---+---+---+")
    print("+ "+choices[0]+" + "+choices[1]+" + "+choices[2]+" +")
    print("+---+---+---+")
    print("+ "+choices[3]+" + "+choices[4]+" + "+choices[5]+" +")
    print("+---+---+---+")
    print("+ "+choices[6]+" + "+choices[7]+" + "+choices[8]+" +")
    print("+---+---+---+")


def getchoice(choices):
    while checkwin(choices)==0:  
        userchoice = int(input ("Where would you like to put your X?"))
        index = userchoice-1
        while choices[index]!=" ":
            userchoice = int(input ("That space is taken. Where would you like to put your X?"))
            index = userchoice-1    
        choices[index]="X"
        board(choices)

        if checkwin(choices)!=1:
            userchoice = int(input ("Where would you like to put your O?"))
            index = userchoice-1
            while choices[index]!=" ":
                userchoice = int(input ("That space is taken. Where would you like to put your O?"))
                index = userchoice-1           
            choices[index]="O"
            board(choices)
    if checkwin(choices)==1:
        print("Player 1 wins")
    elif checkwin(choices)==2:
        print("Player 2 wins")
    else:
        if checkwin(choices)==3:
            print("It's a draw")

    again = input("Would you like to play again? Y/N")
    again = again.upper()
    if again == "Y":
        start()
    else:
        print("Thank you for playing")

def draw(c):
    for i in range(0,8):
        if c[i] ==" ":
            return True
    return False

def checkwin (c):

    if ((c[0]=="X" and c[1]=="X" and c[2]=="X") or
(c[3]=="X"and c[4]=="X" and c[5] =="X") or
(c[6]=="X"and c[7]=="X" and c[8] =="X") or
(c[0]=="X"and c[3]=="X" and c[6] =="X" )or
(c[1]=="X"and c[4]=="X" and c[7] =="X") or
(c[2]=="X"and c[5]=="X" and c[8] =="X") or
(c[0]=="X"and c[4]=="X" and c[8] =="X") or
(c[6]=="X"and c[4]=="X" and c[2] =="X"))==True:
        return 1

    elif ((c[0]=="O" and c[1]=="O" and c[2]=="O") or
(c[3]=="O"and c[4]=="O" and c[5] =="O") or
(c[6]=="O"and c[7]=="O" and c[8] =="O") or
(c[0]=="O"and c[3]=="O" and c[6] =="O" )or
(c[1]=="O"and c[4]=="O" and c[7] =="O") or
(c[2]=="O"and c[5]=="O" and c[8] =="O") or
(c[0]=="O"and c[4]=="O" and c[8] =="O") or
(c[6]=="O"and c[4]=="O" and c[2] =="O")) ==True:
        return 2

    elif draw(c)==False:
        print("DRAW")
        return 3
    else:
        return 0

start()
```

Comment: First of all, I'd change checkwin1 and checkwin2 to checkwin, which returns 0 if nobody won, 1 if the first player won and 2 if player 2 won; Second, I dont really understand. What's the problem? You have to click enter twice for the interpreter to close?

Comment: question: is this python 2 or 3?

Comment: @wavemode judging by the use of `input` 3